# Deployed Azure Function is missing Entity Framework .edmx file - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions

I have a v3 Azure Function that runs fine locally, but after it's deployed I see the following exception related to a missing Entity Framework file:

> 2021-10-18T23:37:07.588 [Error] Executed 'MyFunction' (Failed, Duration=1807ms)
> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while activating
> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'Repository'.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\DAOEntities.edmx'.
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
> at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode,FileShare share,FileOptions options)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,FileMode mode,FileAccess access,FileShare share,Int32 bufferSize,FileOptions options)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path,FileMode mode,FileAccess access,FileShare share,Int32 bufferSize,Boolean useAsync)
> at System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName)
> at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(String outputFileName,XmlWriterSettings settings)
> at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultDbModelStore.Save(Type contextType,DbModel model)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AsNoTracking()   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.AsNoTracking()
> at lambda_method(Closure ,Object[] )
> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
> End of inner exception
> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context,IEnumerable`1 parameters)   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> End of inner exception
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope,ResolveRequest request)   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context,Service service,IEnumerable`1 parameters,Object& instance)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context,Service service,IEnumerable`1 parameters)   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context,IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
> at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AzureFunctions.ScopedJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](ILifetimeScope scope)
> at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AzureFunctions.ScopedJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 20   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 26
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs : 44
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 776
> at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 101

I've noticed locally that the `.edmx` file isn't generated when the project is built -- instead it's created when I start running the project using `func start`.

Could this be a permissions issue (e.g. with the function not having write access to the storage blob)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the root issue is related to the `Run From Package` setting.
This prevents the function app from generating the `.edmx` file, so the solution is to either disable `Run From Package` or to deploy the function with the `.edmx` file pre-included.

From MSDN: Run From Package makes wwwroot read-only, so you will receive an error when writing files to this directory. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package)